# Is there a way to skip the cinematic when resonating with a blade?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

I already know you can skip the "presentation" cinematic of the blade once you've finished resonating. But I'd like to skip the previous cinematic when your character is resonating with the core crystal, so **is there a way to skip it ?** I didn't find any option or button to do so, did I miss something ?

I'm asking this because it seems that you might want to chain resonating at some point to get blades with specific field skill that you might be missing or just complete your roster with specific element and it takes so much time.

My question extends to the "pause" which let you know which level of field skill you used and from which blade which takes forever as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit** as of the 1.3.0 update: You can now skip these cutscenes. Thanks Monolith.

At this time, the initial ~10s cutscene where the character holds the core crystal in front of them, and the blades appear above them is *not* skippable.

The blade-specific cutscene afterwards can be skipped by pausing with + and pressing A.

Comment: This is no longer true - an update has changed this behavior.  Might be worth updating this answer to be accurate again.

Answer (score 3):

[According to Monolith Soft](https://www.nintendo.com/whatsnew/detail/xenoblade-chronicles-2-director-takahashi-reveals-new-update-information), an option to skip the resonating blade cutscene will be coming next week in the v1.30 update.

> There are also five updates that will apply not only to the Advanced New Game Mode, but to your first playthrough, as well.
>
> • A locking mechanism to lock certain Blades in your party.
>
> • **The option to skip the Blade resonating scene.**
>
> • While expanded, the mini-map can display the same icons you have set
>   up on the Skip Travel screen.
>
> • Easy Mode added to the game difficulty. The original game difficulty
>   level is Normal Mode. You can change the difficulty level at any time
>   with the in-game options.
>
> • New sorting options for Accessories, Aux Cores, and Blade Lists.

**Source**: [Nintendo.com - *Xenoblade Chronicles 2: Director Takahashi reveals new update information*](https://www.nintendo.com/whatsnew/detail/xenoblade-chronicles-2-director-takahashi-reveals-new-update-information)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, I don't remember exactly, and I'm at the office so I can't check, but I think It's + to pause then X to skip (while pausing, you have a message telling you how to skip).

Comment: That is not the right cinematic.